# Binding in the client + WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, binding, client

I use visual studio 11 to add service (Add service Reference).
When I added the service Article, I have An articleClient with one constructor:

```
public RssArticleServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }
```

How can I use this constructor, i don't know which value of binding should I use??

Any example or sample please??

Merci

Best regards

---

I do this:

```
BasicHttpSecurityMode securitymode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport; BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(securitymode); binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue; binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue; Uri uri = new Uri("adresse/RssArticleService.svc";); _clientArticles = new RssArticleServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("adresse/RssArticleService.svc";)); var result=await _clientArticles.GetRssDataAsync("1", "fr");
```

And A cath this error:

```
**here was no endpoint listening at adresse/RssArticleService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP**
```

What can i do, should i change the type of binding??

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation :

```
BasicHttpSecurityMode securitymode = HostSource.Scheme.Equals("https", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport : BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(securitymode);
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

Uri uri = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../service.svc");
_client = new RssArticleServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri))
```

EDIT : you need to add this in your web.config :

```
<system.serviceModel> 
<services>
  <service name="namespace.RssArticleService"
           behaviorConfiguration="RssArticleServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="namespace.IRssArticleService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="RssArticleServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
   </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: BasicHttpSecurityMode securitymode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(securitymode);
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

Uri uri = new Uri("https://adresse/RssArticleService.svc");
_clientArticles = new RssArticleServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://adresse/RssArticleService.svc"));
var result=await _clientArticles.GetRssDataAsync("1", "fr");